# Erro ao executar o UPDATE

Tags: php

Ao executar o `UPDATE` ocorreu os seguintes erros:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\guaraparivirtual\count\count.php on line 17

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\guaraparivirtual\count\count.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\guaraparivirtual\count\count.php on line 17
```

**Código:**

```
 <?php include ("../incluir/conexao.php"); ?>

<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];


                $propaganda_count=mysqli_query($con,"select click,link FROM bannersclick where id='$id'");
                while($count_click=mysqli_fetch_array($propaganda_count)){

                    $clickget = $count_click['click'];
                    $linkget = $count_click['link'];
                }

$clickget = $clickget + 1;

    $sqli = "UPDATE bannersclick SET click = '$clickget' where id = '$id'";
    $mysqli->query($sqli);

header( "Location: $linkget" , TRUE , 302 );
?>
```

**A linha 17 dos erros é:** `$mysqli->query($sqli);`

Busquei solucionar, mas não compreendi o motivo do erro.

Comment: Você iniciou uma instancia de $mysqli? Pelo erro, parece que nao.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo erro, parece que nenhuma conexão foi iniciada na variável `$mysqli`. E observando o restante do código adicionado, a variável `$mysqli` não existe até você utilizá-la na linha 17, na query anterior, você utiliza a variável `$conn` para fazer a pesquisa.

Sem alterar demais o código, ao invés de usar uma variável que não existe, utilize a variável de conexão que você utilizou na query anterior:

```
<?php include ("../incluir/conexao.php"); ?>

<?php
    $id = $_GET["id"];

    $propaganda_count=mysqli_query($con,"select click,link FROM bannersclick where id='$id'");

    while($count_click=mysqli_fetch_array($propaganda_count)){
        $clickget = $count_click['click'];
        $linkget = $count_click['link'];
    }

    $clickget = $clickget + 1;

    $sqli = "UPDATE bannersclick SET click = '$clickget' where id = '$id'";
    $conn->query($sqli);

    header( "Location: $linkget" , TRUE , 302 );
?>
```

Atente-se ao que diz a documentação:

> It is possible to switch between styles at any time. Mixing both styles is not recommended for code clarity and coding style reasons.

Ou seja, não é recomendável utilizar os dois modos ao mesmo tempo, por razões de organização e clareza de código.

*Fonte: [Documetação PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php)*

Comment: A conexão foi iniciada, pois ele executa uma rotina acima deste código.

Comment: @Gladison pelo erro, a variavel não foi iniciada, adicione o restante da rotina entao para avaliarmos melhor, porque apenas analisando pela informações passadas, esta resposta resolveria.

Comment: Fiz a inclusão do código completo.

Comment: @Gladison segundo a edicao, o problema é o que eu mencionei, você está utilizando uma variavel não iniciada. `$mysqli` não existe no seu código até a linha 17. Você está misturando o modo procedural com o modo OO, por isso o problema.

Comment: como solucionar? Qual a melhor forma de estruturar este código?

Comment: @Gladison depende da preferencia do programador, eu particulamente prefiro a OO pois já estou habituado a este paradigma. Mas tem que haver coerencia com o restante do código, se ele já está todo procedural, inserir OO pode dificultar sua leitura.

Comment: Qual o motivo do downvote? Se eu não souber o que tem de errado na resposta, não tem como eu corrigir e ela vai continuar errada, caso o voto seja por esse motivo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61611/discussion-between-gladison-and-diegofm).

Comment: Não dei um downvote, onde foi isso? Votei como resposta útil e tb como no "V" como resposta.

Comment: @Gladison eu sei, alguém havia negativado, o comentario era pra pessoa que negativou informar o problema, mas infelizmente ela preferiu se omitir.